# idioms that mean being good at something

Tags: idioms

I am looking for a few idioms that mean either being good at something or simply being generally good. "Ace" is the word I have in mind, unfortunately not an idiom.

Comment: I think this is Too Broad (essentially, it's a "list" question).

Comment: Yes, @FumbleFingers, But it's a nice "list" question!  I am interested in the answers.  Quick people, answer this before it gets closed!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: My closevote comment above is obviously *the dog's bollocks* ('cos I'm a *whiz* at this sort of thing), but even if the question is closed there's nothing to stop people posting hundreds more suggestions as comments.

Comment: That is true, @FumbleFingers. My bad. And thanks for the laugh-inducing comment! You have a way with words; I'd love to meet you one fine day.  Unlikely however, with the Atlantic and the entire continental US standing in the way. :-)

Comment: Damn you guys - this was actually a fun question!

Comment: Yes, it is, @JoeBlow.  Answers can still be given as comments, so all is not lost.  But honestly, the question still falls afoul of the standards for questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous, including

> - top of the heap
> - the cat's meow
> - nec plus ultra
> - icing on the cake
> - the cherry on top
> - king of the jungle
> - king of the mountain
> - king of the hill
> - lord of the manor
> - all that and a bag of chips

and many more.

Comment: The best thing since sliced bread!

Comment: I like kick-ass.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think idioms can be restricted to multiple word phrases.  Single words can be idiomatically understood.  The only single word idiom that occurs to me at the moment is the somewhat dated "crackerjack".  See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crackerjack) on this word.

Comment: Absolutely, an idiom can be a single word.  It's commonplace